# Why doesn't before_filter apply to filter list of displayed products ? (rails4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, before-filter

I have a simple homepage with a list of Deals.

I'd like to filter this list by country using before_filter.

Here is my code on /app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :filter_deals_based_on_visitor_country,
    :only => [ :home]  


  def filter_deals_based_on_visitor_country
    @deals = Deal.find_by(:country => "United States") 
  end    

  def home          
    @deals = Deal.featured_on_hp.to_a

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # home.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @deals }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @deals }
      # format.atom
  end

end
```

But it does not work: on my screen, I see also deals which are not from the United States

It's like the first before filter where I try to set 'only United states country' is overriden by my method "home" that comes after.

Hers is what I get on my console:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-14 12:00:22 +0200
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Deal Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals" WHERE "deals"."country" = 'United States' LIMIT 1
  Deal Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals" WHERE (deal_launch_date <= '2014-06-14 12:00:22.522089' AND deal_end_date >= '2014-06-14 12:00:22.522116') AND "deals"."featured" = 't' ORDER BY deals.created_at DESC
  Rendered layouts/_hp_deal_card.html.erb (5.2ms)
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (317.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_metas.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 351ms (Views: 346.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

For the sake of reference here is the method featured_on_hp, I used (but it has no impact here I think):

app/models/deal.rb

```
scope :featured_on_hp,lambda { default.where('deal_launch_date <= ? AND deal_end_date >= ?', Time.zone.now, Time.zone.now).where(featured: true) }
```

How can I tell Rails to first apply the before_filter and only take deals from the United States, and **only then** apply the method home and get among these US deals those who should be featured today ?

thanks

PS: of course when this problem is solved I will replace "united states" by a variable holding the name of the countries i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home          
    @deals = scope.featured_on_hp

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # home.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @deals }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @deals }
      # format.atom
    end
  end

  private

  def scope
    Deal.where(:country => "United States") 
  end    
end
```

Your `before_filter` is pointless here. If you need to use a particular scope somehow, just write it explicitly.

Comment: OK:) i thought putting in a before_filter would be more efficient and more Rails/DRY

Comment: i think you're right, better to just put it into the scope

Comment: It dry to create a shared method, I agree, but no need to trigger it through a before_filter in this case

Comment: Why not the `#scope` method to get shifted to the *model* ? model logic inside the controller. ;)

Comment: @Arup Rakshit rename it deals if you like, its just the base query for the controller

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your `before_filter` did not work, is it assigns `@deals` and you later *overwrite* this in the `home` action again, undoing whatever you did in the `before_filter`.

I would add a `for_country` method on your model, which returns an ActiveRecord::Relation

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.for_country(country)
    where(country: country)
  end

end
```

and then in your controller you can write

```
def home          
  @deals = Deal.for_country(params[:country] || "United Stated").featured_on_hp

  respond_to do |format| 
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @deals }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @deals }
    # format.atom
  end
end
```

This is of course assuming you specify the country on params (if you do it via the url or a parameter, it will).

Note I would never add the explicit `to_a` call.